# Vagrant setup MongoDB errno 104

Tags: mongodb, vagrant, vagrantfile

Im getting this error::

Any help would be great,thanks in advance

```
An error occurred while downloading the remote file. The error
message, if any, is reproduced below. Please fix this error and try
again.

SSL read: error:00000000:lib(0):func(0):reason(0), errno 104
```

ive changed the permission

```
sudo chown username:username -R ~/.vagrant.d
```

also, removed temp file data.

```
rm -rf ~/.vagrant.d/tmp/box*
```

Answer (score 0):

download the box using the `--insecure` flag, something like

```
vagrant box add ubuntu/trusty64 --insecure
```

and replace `ubuntu/trusty64` by the name of the box you are downloading